# Android Studio code doesn't work on Android Version P 9.0

Tags: android, sqlite, autocompletetextview, dbconnection

Please My Android App works well in any android app version but dont work on android 9.0 ?? there is no errors display when run the code from android studio on emulator, and the problem is that the AutoCompleteTextView doesn't work, but on the other versions higher and lower work well.my code is:

```
AutoCompleteTextView srch_txt=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.srch_txt);
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection(this);
        //SQLiteDatabase dbb = db.getWritableDatabase();//connect to MyDB
        SQLiteDatabase dbb = db.getReadableDatabase();//connect to MyDB
        final String [] mydata;
        //Inside the method you've read the cursor, loop through it and add those item to array
        String sql="SELECT * FROM revuesC";
        //execute SQL
        Cursor cr= dbb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        mydata = new String[cr.getCount()];//create array string based on numbers of row
        int i=0;
        while (cr.moveToNext()) {
            mydata[i]= cr.getString(1);
            i++;
        }
        cr.moveToFirst();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,mydata);
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
        //AutoCompleteTextView actv =  (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        srch_txt.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
        srch_txt.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
        cr.close();

> Blockquote
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issues by adding this @override method in my DBConnectionHelper:

```
@Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
```